# Does android support EAP-SIM?

Tags: java, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.3, sim-card

We have a radius server that able to authenticate a mobile device using EAP-SIM. I've searched the net and they've suggested to make your own android 2.3.5 OS build and implement some patches. Is there any easier way to do, same with the iPhone Configuration Screen on iTunes. Cause i have to download a GB of data from their repository.

Comment: i've tried to read this link [link]http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android and its time consuming for RnD but its great to know that there are someone who develop this kid of technology.

Comment: Did you find answer to this? Looks there is not available other than on some Samsung and Sony mobiles.